# Rich media in itext7

Tags: itext7

itext 5 provides a number of classes related to rich media:

- RichMediaAnnotation
- RichMediaConfiguration
- RichMediaInstance
- RichMediaParams
- RichMediaActivation

there is also an example that explains how to use them to insert a flash program in a pdf:

http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-16#608-festivalcalendar1.java

However, in itext 7 the only object that I found related to rich media is 
PdfRichMediaAnnotation. I couldn't find either any example that shows how to use it.

How can I insert an SWF program in a pdf with itext 7?

Comment: Embedded SWF is deprecated in ISO-32000-2 (aka PDF 2.0), and since iText 7 was created with PDF 2.0 in mind, we won't support embedding SWF. It just doesn't make sense to do the investment (not for us, **but also not for you or your company**) because soon there won't be any viewer that supports SWF in PDF Rich Media Annotations.